# Sourcing /root/.zshrc in Docker using current user

Tags: docker

I am trying to build my container for a root user and then run it with my user and source the `/root/.zshrc` from inside.

Here is a minimal example:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt update 
RUN apt install --assume-yes --fix-broken \
    curl \
    wget \
    zsh

RUN echo EDITOR=vim >> /root/.zshrc

RUN chmod a+rx /root
CMD [ "source /root/.zshrc", "zsh"]
```

The invocation is as follows:

```bsh
docker run --rm -it -v "$HOME/.ssh:$HOME/.ssh:ro" -v "$HOME/.netrc:$HOME/.netrc:ro" -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro -v /etc/shadow:/etc/shadow:ro -v /etc/group:/etc/group:ro --user $UID:$UID foo_minimal
```

The error that I'm getting is:

```bsh
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"source /root/.zshrc\": stat source /root/.zshrc: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: You've described the approach you're taking to solve a problem, but haven't described the problem you're trying to solve.  You almost certainly don't want to mount `/etc/{passwd,group}` into the container.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Oh, sorry for that. I am trying to make my host user the same as the user inside the docker container. I would like to build the container once and make it available for any user that runs it. Those users will mount volumes from host which they will modify. If they don't mount their users, accessing those files outside of the container might lead to permission problems. What would be a better way to do it?

Comment: You can make the uid/gid match w/o mapping in `/etc/{passwd,group}`.

Comment: yes, that's what I'm aiming at by --user $UID:$UID, but that's just an int, not the actual user name. I don't know how to "mount" the username and also don't know how to mount the group..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move forward with your original approach, and if you're just looking to update a file that will be sourced by `zsh` when you log in, you can append to `/etc/zsh/zshrc`:

```
RUN echo EDITOR=vim >> /etc/zsh/zshrc
```

Then whatever user runs the container, it'll automatically source that file.

Answer (score 1):

If users to have a username and shell RC file, you might consider creating it as part of your Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt update && \
    apt install --assume-yes --fix-broken \
    curl \
    wget \
    zsh

RUN groupadd -g 1000 bob && \
    useradd -m --uid 1000 --gid 1000 -s /bin/zsh bob && \
    echo EDITOR=vim >> /home/bob/.zshrc

CMD [ "zsh" ]
```

Here, I add a group named `bob` with gid 1000 and a user named `bob` with uid 1000 (you can change `bob` to be whatever the name is that's associated with uid 1000.

Then, you can write to that user's `~/.zshrc` instead of `/root/.zshrc`

Comment: Yes, but you are then forcing different users to all use the user bob, not their own username.

Comment: @MihaiGalos you can run `useradd` more than once...  I assume you're not talking about tens of users here.

Answer (score 0):

I got it running :

created a file called .zshrc sourcing /root/.zshrc and mounted it in user home:

```bsh
~/git/docker/base-ubuntu-20.04/test-delete(allow_multiuser*) » cat .zshrc                                                                                                         mihai@mihai-pc 17/10/20 21:07:24
#!/bin/zsh

source /root/.zshrc
```

and then:

```bsh
~/git/docker/base-ubuntu-20.04/test-delete(allow_multiuser*) » docker run -it -v "$HOME/.ssh:$HOME/.ssh:ro" -v "$HOME/.netrc:$HOME/.netrc:ro" -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro -v /etc/shadow:/etc/shadow:ro -v /etc/group:/etc/group:ro --user $UID:$UID --env "$USER=$USER" -v $(realpath .zshrc):/home/$USER/.zshrc foo_minimal /bin/zsh          

df45e8b82593% echo $EDITOR
vim
```

What do you think of this solution?

Comment: I suggest that you append `/etc/zsh/zshrc` and leave `/root/.zshrc` out of the picture all together.

Comment: Thank you very much AndyDalton! That worked flawlessly. Can you post this as an answer, as it exactly solves my problem!